# How to get back vim files after deleting them / completely reinstall vim?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

Vim on terminal, Ubuntu 14.04.

While messing with vim syntax files and color files, I accidentally deleted all vim file from **/usr/share/**

I originally installed vim with *sudo apt-get install vim*

To get back the files, I tried:

*sudo apt-get remove, install, update, upgrade,* and  *hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim* and make. The files I got with make doesn't seem to do much for me and are not identical to what I had before with *get install vim* in *usr/share/* folder

with *apt-get install*, normal vim works but no syntax, color or other available things that was in vim file are all missing.

How do I completely reinstall vim / get back the default files?

Thanks

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall <package>` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Just found it,

> sudo apt-get purge vim
>
> sudo apt-get install vim

seems to fix it for me. I spent unnecessarily too long on this to find a solution. Oh, well.